# Any optimization about random access array modification?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, optimization, memory

Given an array A of size 10<sup>5</sup>.

Then given m (m is very large, m>> the size of A) operations, each operation is for position p, increasing t.

A[p]+=t

Finally, I output the value of each position of the whole array.

Is there any constant optimization to speed up the intermediate modification operations?

For example, if I sort the positions, I can modify them sequentially to avoid random access. However, this operation will incur an additional sorting cost. Is there any other way to speed it up?

Trying to re-execute all operations after sorting can be an order of magnitude faster than executing them directly. But the cost of sorting is too high.

Comment: I can't say, but is m very large with respect to the size of the array? Basically guaranteeing that all array entries are touched, or is m << array size. These kinds of things matter. But I suspect performance is mostly related to whether the data fits in cache or not (and possibly branch/prefetch prediction). There are more then enough examples where sorting first can lead to an overal performance gain. But in the end there is only one way : try and measure (benchmark) and find your bottlenecks.

Comment: This is hardly answerable without benchmarking. Seems to me that it is not that hard to test with/without extra `std::sort` call.

Comment: What is the type of `A` and `p` and what is the expected target processor (the reference if you know it or the architecture otherwise if possible)?

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On architectures with many cores, the best solution is certainly to perform atomic accesses of `A[p]` in parallel. This assume the number of cores is sufficiently big for the parallelism to not only mitigate the overhead of the atomic operations but also be faster than the serial implementation. This can be pretty easily done with OpenMP or with native C++ thread/atomics. The number of core need not to be too huge, otherwise, the number of conflict may be significantly bigger causing contention and so decreasing performance. This should be fine since the number of item is pretty big. This solution also assume the accesses are quite uniformly random. If they are not (eg. normal distribution), then the contention can be too big for the method to be efficient.

An alternative solution is to split the accesses between N threads spacially. The array range can be statically split in N (relatively equal) parts. All the threads read the inputs but only the thread owning the target range of the output array write into it. The array parts can then be combined after that. This method works well with few threads and if the data distribution is uniform. When the distribution is not uniform at all (eg. normal distribution), then a pre-computing step may be needed so to adjust the array range owned by threads. For example, one can compute the median, or event the quartiles so to better balance the work between threads. Computing quartiles can be done using a partitioning algorithm like [Floyd Rivest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Rivest_algorithm) (`std::partition` should not be too bad despite I expect it to use a kind of IntroSelect algorithm that is often a bit slower). The pre-computation may be expensive but this should be significantly faster than doing a sort. Using OpenMP is certainly a good idea to implement this.

Another alternative implementation is simply to perform the reduction separately in each thread and then sum up the final array of each thread in a global array. This solution works well in your case (since "m >> the size of A") assuming the number of core is not too big. If so, on need to mix this method with the first one. This last method is probably the simplest efficient method.

Comment: That's an excellent point! And I Upped for the detailed analysis.  Just a friendly reminder, the memory-dirty-bit issue would play a very important role in the performance for this shared memory thread-based OpenMP mode.

Answer (score 0):

Besides, @Jérôme Richard's answer targeted parallel thread computing.

I would name an idea of the **partial sort** like "merge-sort-just-a-few-iterations" or "bucket-sort-only-in-bucket" (note, they are different).   Preferably, set the bulk size to be the Page size to have a better overall performance in terms of OS level. Especially considering `m` is extraordinarily big. The cost of the partial sort would be amortized by saving cache miss and page swap.

And if this is an interview question, I would ask for more details about `m`, `p`, `t`, data sparsity, distribution, hardware, CPU, memory, power consumption, latency, .etc details. And for each new condition, customizes more detailed designs accordingly.